# how actualy OCR app works . what methods use for it?

Tags: android, ocr

apps like "camscaner" has OCR feature. actually how is it works as a program ? what methods called in libraries? how to write a program that can identify text in camera?

Comment: you are going to have to do some homework and try some code/integration, for assistance in pushing the project in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Google Play Vision Library `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'` to gradle's dependencies &

`<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
    android:value="ocr"/>`

to `AndroidMenifest.xml` as shown here :

[image]

Comment: what is the process of OCR ?

Comment: how to write simple program to detect text?   without using library?  just simple program to get the idea

Comment: Well, if you don't want to add any library, its up to you.

You will need to train a model on your own using Tensorflow (Machine Learning). Which will be able to recognize according to how good the training data was.

Comment: You simply can't write a 5 line program that works as a handwriting expert.